# svg genrated with angular ng-repeat is not rendeerd

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to generate some svg element trough angular ng-repeat

I created one directives that should just import the template

this is the code with the ng repeat

```
<svg width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;" >
    <text x="10" y="10">Project Title</text>    
    <c-object-draggable ng-repeat="cObject in cObjects" ng-controller="cObjectCtrl">
    </c-object-draggable>       
</svg>
```

this is what I have in the template that I'm loading via the c-Object-draggable directiv

```
<g  transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,100,100)">
    <text x="1" y="1">ciao </text>
    <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="20"></circle>
</g>
```

The result in the browser looks good, I can copy it in an other file and it will be correctly rendered.

```
<svg width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
   <text x="10" y="10">Project Title</text> 
   <!-- ngRepeat: cObject in cObjects -->
   <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,100,100)" ng-repeat="cObject in cObjects" ng-controller="cObjectCtrl">
      <text x="1" y="1">ciao </text>
      <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="20"></circle>
  </g>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: cObject in cObjects -->
  <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,100,100)" ng-repeat="cObject in cObjects" ng-controller="cObjectCtrl">
      <text x="1" y="1">ciao </text>
      <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="20"></circle>
  </g>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: cObject in cObjects -->
  <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,100,100)" ng-repeat="cObject in cObjects" ng-controller="cObjectCtrl">
     <text x="1" y="1">ciao </text>
     <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="20"></circle>
  </g>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: cObject in cObjects -->        
</svg>
```

the first text object generated outside the ng-repeat of my directive is correctly displayed. But all the rest is invisible.

It appears if I add a new element modifying the html in the browser everything gets rendered.
Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hoods AngularJS uses JQuery or JQLite to create elements from templates to replace with.

JQuery and JQLite both use document.createElement rather than document.createElementNS with the correct SVG namespace.

<s>In your directive you need to take over the creation of SVG elements from AngularJS.</s>

You can inject the following helper function into your directive:

```
.value('createSVGNode', function(name, element, settings) {
  var namespace = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
  var node = document.createElementNS(namespace, name);
  for (var attribute in settings) {
    var value = settings[attribute];
    if (value !== null && !attribute.match(/\$/) && (typeof value !== 'string' || value !== '')) {
      node.setAttribute(attribute, value);
    }
  }
  return node;
})
```

And make use of it in the link function rather than using a template (either external or inline) - something like:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var cx = '{{x}';
  var cy = '{{y}}';
  var r = '{{r}}';
  var circle = createSVGNode('circle', element, attrs);

  angular.element(circle).attr('ng-attr-cx', cx);
  angular.element(circle).attr('ng-attr-cy', cy);
  angular.element(circle).attr('ng-attr-r', r);
  element.replaceWith(circle);

  $compile(circle)(scope);
}
```

You can see an example of this working - in a piechart context - over at https://github.com/mjgodfrey83/angular-piechart/.

A fix landed in angular 1.3.0-beta8 to allow non html directive template types to be specified - see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f0e12ea7fea853192e4eead00b40d6041c5f914a). For an example of it being used check out [angular-charts](https://github.com/mjgodfrey83/angular-piechart/).

Hope that helps.